# Windows Embedded 7 Standard system requirements

Tags: embedded

I've searched the Microsoft site from one ende to thte other and cannot find the system requirements for Embedded Standard 7 for a device - I can only find the requirements to develop...

Anyone know the requirements?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found it [here on MDSN forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/quebeccomponentsforum/thread/f3def14f-7450-4ae7-9975-6898fa2a5fb2/).

> Hardware requirements WES 2011, as per CTP documentation , (these are unlikely to change dramatically for RTM)
>
> The embedded device must meet or
>   exceed the following requirements:
>
> - 1 GHz x86 or amd64 processor
> - 512 MB of system memory (1GB recommended for amd64)
> - 900 mhz CPU or equivalent
> - 1 GB free space on hard disk drive (HDD) or flash-based Solid State Drive
>     (SSD) (4 GB recommended)
> - At least one of the following bootable media types:
> - Bootable DVD-ROM drive
> - Bootable USB 2.0 port and a USB Flash Drive (UFD) with 4 GB of free
>     space, or access to a local network
> - BIOS Supporting Windows Preinstallation Environment (Windows
>     PE) 3.0

Answer (score 0):

Go to [this page](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsembedded/en-us/windows-embedded.aspx), and select a scenario from the drop down box.

It will take you to a page and show you the recommended product, along with the relevant specification required for the product.

Comment: Thanks for the link - I've been there before. All it tells you for Standard is the CPU type and 560 megabyte size at the smallest.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the [official requirements](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ff794877(v=winembedded.60).aspx) as posted by Microsoft.
Also see "Requirements for an Embedded Device" for other such requirements from the menu on the left hand side.

The embedded device must meet or exceed the following requirements:

  1 GHz x86 or amd64 processor with 900 mhz speed or equivalent

  512 MB of system memory (1GB recommended for amd64)

  1 GB free space on hard disk drive (HDD) or flash-based Solid State Drive (SSD) (4 GB recommended)

At least one of the following bootable media types:

  Bootable DVD-ROM drive

  Bootable USB 2.0 port and a USB Flash Drive (UFD) with 4 GB of free space, or access to a local network

  BIOS Supporting Windows Preinstallation Environment (Windows PE) 3.0

Comment: The link does not solve the problem; it explains the requirements for the development machine\

Comment: This is true Luke but that is why I put the second sentence which does explain the requirements for embedded devices. Thus, both sides of the equation are met.

Comment: Side Note: I have searched high and low just to find this official page, I didn't want to really on just a forum post.